# Insert bash one-liner into MySQL row and using bash in python

Tags: python, mysql, bash

I am working on a python script that can pull out bash one-liners from a MySQL database.

What I am trying to do is insert the following into a row as a value, but I get a syntax error as it attempts to process some of the bash code.

```
INSERT INTO email (command1) VALUE ("sudo cat /var/log/exim_mainlog | grep "A\=dovecot_login" | awk -F"A=dovecot_login:" {'print $2'} | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | awk {'print $1, " unique emails sent by " , $2'}")
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: 
Unknown command '\='.
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A\=dovecot_login" | awk -F"A=dovecot_login:" {'print $2'} | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort' at line 1
```

What would be the best way to import information like this?  Or for python, would there be a recommended way of calling data like this instead of MySQL?  Right now if I have them stored in a python module, I have to put in \ and add additional "s in order for it to process it properly.  Is there an alternate way I can call for bash one-liners in python without having to edit them to make them python friendly?

Comment: You need to escape the `"`, otherwise it ends the string. Or use a single quote instead of double quote.

Comment: @Barmar, you are the man!